# Unable to determine ZooKeeper ensemble

Tags: hbase, hdfs, apache-zookeeper

Status:

1. Zookeeper is running
2. Hbase master also running fine and waiting for any regionserver

Now when I start the region server I recieve the following error:

```
17/04/24 20:13:23 ERROR master.HMaster: Region server icosa4,60020,1493045002304 reported a fatal error:
ABORTING region server icosa4,60020,1493045002304: Unhandled exception: Unable to determine ZooKeeper ensemble
Cause:
java.io.IOException: Unable to determine ZooKeeper ensemble
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.connect(ZKUtil.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationPeer.reloadZkWatcher(ReplicationPeer.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationPeer.<init>(ReplicationPeer.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationZookeeper.getPeer(ReplicationZookeeper.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationZookeeper.connectToPeer(ReplicationZookeeper.java:308)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationZookeeper.connectExistingPeers(ReplicationZookeeper.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationZookeeper.<init>(ReplicationZookeeper.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.regionserver.Replication.initialize(Replication.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.newReplicationInstance(HRegionServer.java:4035)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.createNewReplicationInstance(HRegionServer.java:4004)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.setupWALAndReplication(HRegionServer.java:1416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.handleReportForDutyResponse(HRegionServer.java:1100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:753)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/04/24 20:13:23 INFO zookeeper.RegionServerTracker: RegionServer ephemeral node deleted, processing expiration [icosa4,60020,1493045002304]
```

On starting region server the following error is logged:

```
17/04/24 20:42:20 INFO replication.ReplicationZookeeper: Replication is now started
17/04/24 20:42:20 INFO zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper: Node /hbase/replication/state already exists and this is not a retry
17/04/24 20:42:20 WARN zookeeper.ZKConfig: java.net.UnknownHostException: PBUF
5icosa4: unknown error
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKConfig.getZKQuorumServersString(ZKConfig.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKConfig.getZKQuorumServersString(ZKConfig.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationPeer.reloadZkWatcher(ReplicationPeer.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationPeer.<init>(ReplicationPeer.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationZookeeper.getPeer(ReplicationZookeeper.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationZookeeper.connectToPeer(ReplicationZookeeper.java:308)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationZookeeper.connectExistingPeers(ReplicationZookeeper.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationZookeeper.<init>(ReplicationZookeeper.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.regionserver.Replication.initialize(Replication.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.newReplicationInstance(HRegionServer.java:4035)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.createNewReplicationInstance(HRegionServer.java:4004)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.setupWALAndReplication(HRegionServer.java:1416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.handleReportForDutyResponse(HRegionServer.java:1100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:753)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/04/24 20:42:20 ERROR zookeeper.ZKConfig: no valid quorum servers found in zoo.cfg
17/04/24 20:42:20 WARN regionserver.HRegionServer: Exception in region server : 
java.io.IOException: Unable to determine ZooKeeper ensemble
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.connect(ZKUtil.java:116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:127)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationPeer.reloadZkWatcher(ReplicationPeer.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationPeer.<init>(ReplicationPeer.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationZookeeper.getPeer(ReplicationZookeeper.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationZookeeper.connectToPeer(ReplicationZookeeper.java:308)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationZookeeper.connectExistingPeers(ReplicationZookeeper.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.ReplicationZookeeper.<init>(ReplicationZookeeper.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.replication.regionserver.Replication.initialize(Replication.java:105)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.newReplicationInstance(HRegionServer.java:4035)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.createNewReplicationInstance(HRegionServer.java:4004)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.setupWALAndReplication(HRegionServer.java:1416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.handleReportForDutyResponse(HRegionServer.java:1100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.run(HRegionServer.java:753)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/04/24 20:42:20 INFO regionserver.HRegionServer: STOPPED: Failed initialization
17/04/24 20:42:20 ERROR regionserver.HRegionServer: Failed init
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding this to `conf/hbase-site.xml` :

```
<property>
   <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
   <value>/hbase-unsecure</value>
</property>
```